# Appending a div

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm coding my own sort of commentfield for my website, so im trying out using the append function in jquery, but netbeans is telling me this function call is missing quotes

```
$( "#comment" ).append( "<div class="userComment">
    <b>testName</b>
          <p>TestText</p>
      </div>" );
```

Comment: Use single-quotes around the class name: `( "<div class='userComment'...`

Comment: You can't break a string onto multiple lines in JavaScript as far as I know. Meaning you'll have to concatenate:

    $("#comment").append("<div class=\"userComment\"> "+
    "<b>testName</b>"+
    "      <p>TestText</p>"+
    "  </div>");

Comment: @WordsLikeJared You can also escape the newline characters.

Comment: @undefined Oh like C-style syntax.  Didn't know that.  http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```
$( "#comment" ).append( '<div class="userComment"><b>testName</b><p>TestText</p></div>' );
```